# UML Which arrow to connect concrete class and its abstract class?

Tags: java, uml

Here, in the only answer, it's a simple arrow:
[How to present an abstract class in UML class diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049761/how-to-present-an-abstract-class-in-uml-class-diagram)

But here, it's similar to the interface arrow:
[http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~jsa/UMLJavaShortCourse09/CGOutput/Unit9/unit9(0809)/page_03.htm](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/%7Ejsa/UMLJavaShortCourse09/CGOutput/Unit9/unit9(0809)/page_03.htm)

I'm thinking it should be the same arrow as class to interface arrow of the diagram; is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The picture you reference shows a generalization. In that case the three concrete classes below just inherit from the abstract class on top. The isAbstract property of the top class just tells that you can not instantiate it directly. You must derive concrete classes (which inherit attributes/operations).

The assocation in the referenced answer just tells that the concrete class `Structure` deals with concrete classes derived from `Contexte`. You see three generalizations to the right which for sure will be those concrete classes.

N.B. Inheriting from an abstract class is "similar" to realizing an interface.

Comment: Ah; I misunderstood `Structure` in the referenced answer to be the `Contexte`'s implementing class. Thanks @qwerty_so