# How to present the abstract method in the child classes in a class Diagram

Tags: java, class, uml, abstract

I am doing a class diagram and I have one abstract class and two child classes which inherit from the parent one. The abstract class has also 2 abstract methods.My question is,should I add the abstract methods in the child classes in my class diagram ? Since its a abstract method I know that they have to be implemented in the inherited classes. This is my diagram :

[image]

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049761/how-to-present-an-abstract-class-in-uml-class-diagram) question helps you

Comment: A class is a classifier, and an abstract classifier if written in italic, see § 9.2.4.1 page 101 of http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1

Comment: Re. _repeating_: You don't repeat the anstract opertion. Instead you present a concrete implementation of it.